# Livestreaming Website Architecture Design

Tags: architecture, webrtc, load-balancing, load-testing, rtsp

I want to build a website that can display live streams to multiple users (<100) with a latency of <500ms. The source of the live streams will be from different raspberry piess camera module.

So far the architecture I have thought of is the following:

Raspberry Pies - broadcasting the streams over to my web server using RTSP

Web Server - Running Apache/Nginx + Janus Gateway (to receive and convert the RTSP streams into WebRTC and forward the stream to clients)

Clients - Users running Chrome, Firefox, Safari

My questions are:

1. Is there anything missing from this setup and if not, will this setup be able to deliver <500ms delay streams to my users or is this something I can only find out by implementing and measuring it by myself? Other tech stacks I can consider?
2. How would I perform load testing/load balancing on my web server? (would need some keywords/tools to google search for myself)

Comment: The question really is how high the resolution and Bitrate is supposed to be, how much bandwidth your Webserver has and how much cpu and / or potentially graphics power it has.

Comment: I'm just wondering if these protocols/tools are appropriate to get the lowest possible latency or is there anything else I could try? As for resolution I would like to stream in 720p.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you should think about ability to add more server(s) plus [load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/) and/or [horizontal scaling](https://groups.google.com/g/meetecho-janus/c/F-VL6L40BPY) if a single server instance won't be able to handle the anticipated number of clients with the acceptable latency
2. There are services like [TestRTC](https://testrtc.com/stress-sizing/) which you could use for load testing your deployment, if you prefer free and open source solutions you can take a look at [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) plus [JSR223 Test Elements with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) plus [GStreamer](https://github.com/gstreamer-java)